# steady states and stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

im just checking to see if im doing this right?

$$\frac{du}{d\tau}=u(1-u)-h    $$

show this equations has 2 steady states and check their linear stability.

this is what i have done:

$u=0$ and $u=1$

$$\frac{d^2u}{d\tau^2} = -2u+1    $$

at $u=0$, $\frac{d^2u}{d\tau^2}$=1 which is unstable

at $u=1$, $\frac{d^2u}{d\tau^2}$=-1 which is stable

is this right? thanks in advance

Comment: The second derivative is with respect to u, not tau.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steady states occur when the RHS is zero, so

$$u-u^2-h = 0$$

which gives you steady states at

$$u^\pm = \tfrac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4h})$$

You can then plug these values into the second derivative, which you already computed, to determine their stability (though make sure you have the signs the right way around - positive is unstable, negative is stable!)

Comment: thank you very much- yes i edited it straight after i realised i go tthe signs for stability the wrong way around. many thanks

Comment: And to avoid computing any derivative, just plot the function $u\mapsto u(1-u)-h$ and the result should jump at your face.

Comment: Hi dear @ChrisTaylor, you solved this question perfectly. Please can you share your ideas about the similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432966/i-want-to-learn-how-to-determine-the-stability-condition-without-using-eigenvalu?noredirect=1#comment7062870_3432966 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A steady state occurs when all derivatives with respect to time are zero. That is, in this case,

$$
\frac{du}{d\tau} = u(1-u)-h = 0
$$
We can rewrite this as

$$
u^2-u+h=0
$$
It is this equation that must be solved for $u$ to get the steady states.

The approach to stability, I believe to be correct (although sign may be backwards - you need to check that), but it must be applied at the correct steady states.

Comment: thank you very much for your help- much appreciated